# How do move alignment line in Intellij in code-view portfolio?

Tags: display-settings, intellij-idea, preview

I would like to move with this alignment in Intellij vertically or just simply remove it.

[Screenshot from Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d32x5.jpg)

I am trying to find options for that particular aligment in Settings but can not find anzthing relevant.

Comment: Editor -> Appearance -> Show right margin

Comment: @DavidPostill Sir, in my IntelliJ 2020 is not that option.